# How to fix node.js using sails error: Failed to lift app

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, sails.js

I’m trying to deploy a node.js app using the framework Sails in production mode.

I’m using the command `npm start` which runs `NODE_ENV=production node app.js`. In `package.json` I have the following content:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "a Sails application",
  "keywords": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "sails": "^1.2.3",
    "grunt": "1.0.4",
    "sails-hook-apianalytics": "^2.0.3",
    "sails-hook-grunt": "^3.0.2",
    "sails-hook-organics": "^0.16.0",
    "sails-hook-orm": "^2.1.1",
    "sails-hook-sockets": "^2.0.0",
    "@sailshq/connect-redis": "^3.2.1",
    "@sailshq/socket.io-redis": "^5.2.0",
    "@sailshq/lodash": "^3.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "5.16.0",
    "htmlhint": "0.11.0",
    "lesshint": "6.3.6",
    "@sailshq/eslint": "^4.19.3",
    "sails-hook-grunt": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node app.js",
    "test": "npm run lint && npm run custom-tests && echo 'Done.'",
    "lint": "./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js . --max-warnings=0 --report-unused-disable-directives && echo '✔  Your .js files look so good.' && ./node_modules/htmlhint/bin/htmlhint -c ./.htmlhintrc views/*.ejs && ./node_modules/htmlhint/bin/htmlhint -c ./.htmlhintrc views/**/*.ejs && ./node_modules/htmlhint/bin/htmlhint -c ./.htmlhintrc views/**/**/*.ejs && ./node_modules/htmlhint/bin/htmlhint -c ./.htmlhintrc views/**/**/**/*.ejs && ./node_modules/htmlhint/bin/htmlhint -c ./.htmlhintrc views/**/**/**/**/*.ejs && ./node_modules/htmlhint/bin/htmlhint -c ./.htmlhintrc views/**/**/**/**/**/*.ejs && ./node_modules/htmlhint/bin/htmlhint -c ./.htmlhintrc views/**/**/**/**/**/**/*.ejs && echo '✔  So do your .ejs files.' && ./node_modules/lesshint/bin/lesshint assets/styles/ --max-warnings=0 && echo '✔  Your .less files look good, too.'",
    "custom-tests": "echo \"(No other custom tests yet.)\" && echo",
    "deploy": "echo 'This script assumes a dead-simple, opinionated setup on Heroku.' && echo 'But, of course, you can deploy your app anywhere you like.' && echo '(Node.js/Sails.js apps are supported on all modern hosting platforms.)' && echo && echo 'Warning: Specifically, this script assumes you are on the master branch, and that your app can be deployed simply by force-pushing on top of the *deploy* branch.  It will also temporarily use a local *predeploy* branch for preparing assets, that it will delete after it finishes.  Please make sure there is nothing you care about on either of these two branches!!!' && echo '' && echo '' && echo 'Preparing to deploy...' && echo '--' && git status && echo '' && echo '--' && echo 'I hope you are on the master branch and have everything committed/pulled/pushed and are completely up to date and stuff.' && echo '********************************************'  && echo '** IF NOT THEN PLEASE PRESS <CTRL+C> NOW! **' && echo '********************************************' && echo 'Press CTRL+C to cancel.' && echo '(you have five seconds)' && sleep 1 && echo '...4' && sleep 1 && echo '...3' && sleep 1 && echo '...2' && sleep 1 && echo '...1' && sleep 1  && echo '' && echo 'Alright, here we go.  No turning back now!' && echo 'Trying to switch to master branch...' && git checkout master && echo && echo 'OK.  Now wiping node_modules/ and running npm install...' && rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && (git add package-lock.json && git commit -am 'AUTOMATED COMMIT: Did fresh npm install before deploying, and it caused something relevant (probably the package-lock.json file) to change!  This commit tracks that change.' || true) && echo 'Deploying as version:' && npm version patch && echo '' && git push origin master && git push --tags && (git branch -D predeploy > /dev/null 2>&1 || true) && git checkout -b predeploy && (echo 'Now building+minifying assets for production...' && echo '(Hang tight, this could take a while.)' && echo && node node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt buildProd || (echo && echo '------------------------------------------' && echo 'IMPORTANT!  IMPORTANT!  IMPORTANT!' && echo 'ERROR: Could not compile assets for production!' && echo && echo 'Attempting to recover automatically by stashing, ' && echo 'switching back to the master branch, and then ' && echo 'deleting the predeploy branch... ' && echo && echo 'After this, please fix the issues logged above' && echo 'and push that up.  Then, try deploying again.' && echo '------------------------------------------' && echo && echo 'Staging, deleting the predeploy branch, and switching back to master...' && git stash && git checkout master && git branch -D predeploy && false)) && mv www .www && git add .www && node -e 'sailsrc = JSON.parse(require(\"fs\").readFileSync(\"./.sailsrc\", \"utf8\"));  if (sailsrc.paths&&sailsrc.paths.public !== undefined || sailsrc.hooks&&sailsrc.hooks.grunt !== undefined) { throw new Error(\"Cannot complete deployment script: .sailsrc file has conflicting contents!  Please throw away this midway-complete deployment, switch back to your original branch (master), remove the conflicting stuff from .sailsrc, then commit and push that up.\"); }  sailsrc.paths = sailsrc.paths || {};  sailsrc.paths.public = \"./.www\";   sailsrc.hooks = sailsrc.hooks || {};  sailsrc.hooks.grunt = false;  require(\"fs\").writeFileSync(\"./.sailsrc\", JSON.stringify(sailsrc))' && git commit -am 'AUTOMATED COMMIT: Automatically bundling compiled assets as part of deploy, updating the EJS layout and .sailsrc file accordingly.' && git push origin predeploy && git checkout master && git push origin +predeploy:deploy && git push --tags && git branch -D predeploy && git push origin :predeploy && echo '' && echo '--' && echo 'OK, done.  It should be live momentarily on your staging environment.' && echo '(if you get impatient, check the Heroku dashboard for status)' && echo && echo 'Staging environment:' && echo ' –•  https://staging.example.com' && echo '       (hold ⌘ and click to open links in the terminal)' && echo && echo 'Please review that to make sure it looks good.' && echo 'When you are ready to go to production, visit your pipeline on Heroku and press the PROMOTE TO PRODUCTION button.'"
  },
  "main": "app.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/xxxxxx.git"
  },
  "author": "me",
  "license": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": "^10.16"
  }
}
```

If I run sails lift all gone right.

And when run `npm start` I get following error:

```
error: Failed to lift app: Error: Should not specify a trailing slash, but instead got: https://myapp.herokuapp.com/
    at checkOriginUrl (/home/me/Documents/prog/myapp/node_modules/sails-hook-sockets/lib/util/check-origin-url.js:57:40)
    at /home/me/Documents/prog/myapp/node_modules/sails-hook-sockets/lib/configure.js:86:9
    at arrayEach (/home/me/Documents/prog/myapp/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:1470:13)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/home/me/Documents/prog/myapp/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3532:13)
    at Hook.configure (/home/me/Documents/prog/myapp/node_modules/sails-hook-sockets/lib/configure.js:85:9)
    at Hook.wrapper [as configure] (/home/me/Documents/prog/myapp/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3282:19)
    at /home/me/Documents/prog/myapp/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/loadHooks.js:331:20
    at /home/me/Documents/prog/myapp/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3083:16
    at eachOfArrayLike (/home/me/Documents/prog/myapp/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1003:9)
    at eachOf (/home/me/Documents/prog/myapp/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1051:5)
    at Object.eachLimit (/home/me/Documents/prog/myapp/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3145:5)
    at configure (/home/me/Documents/prog/myapp/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/loadHooks.js:328:17)
    at /home/me/Documents/prog/myapp/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3853:24
    at replenish (/home/me/Documents/prog/myapp/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:946:17)
    at iterateeCallback (/home/me/Documents/prog/myapp/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:931:17)
    at /home/me/Documents/prog/myapp/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:906:16
```

I’m trying to use heroku to deploy the app. For this reason I added this in `production.js` inside sockets object:

```
    onlyAllowOrigins:[
      'https://myapp.herokuapp.com/',
    ],
```

I think this problem could be caused by any missed configuration in `production.js` but I couldn’t identify what.

Comment: "Should not specify a trailing slash"
You probably want to set `onlyAllowOrigins:[ 'https://myapp.herokuapp.com' ]`

Comment: Yes!! It works. Thanks.